# Crafting a Context Free Grammar

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I'm trying to figure out the intuition on creating a CFG in my head. I understand the idea of Grammar rules akin to "onions" with various layers throughout. For example, I was working on a problem earlier where I was to construct a CFG of $a^ib^jc^k$ with $i \ne j$ OR $j \ne k$. Obviously I separated the problem into two parts, $i$ not being $j$ and the other part being $j$ not being $k$. Taking the left part into account I wrote out the  following:

$$\begin{align*}
S &\to aSbTc \mid aS \mid bT \\
T &\to bTc \mid bc \\
D &\to cD
\end{align*}$$
Am I correct in this for $i$ not being $j$ or is there something in my head thats wrong in thinking through this?

Comment: Taking a look at your first production rule, you could end up with the derivation S -> aSbTc -> aaSbTcbTc which no longer matches the desired pattern. I also don't see how the last production rule D -> cD is being used.

Comment: @roctothorpe Thanks for the suggested edit . I'm having a hard time figuring out how to  rectify that, I thought the last production rule was to allow as many cs as possible?

Comment: @Marorin The production rule $D \to cD$ produces an arbitrary number of $c$'s, but $D$ remains part of the produced word, so the process never terminates. Even worse, $D$ is not even reachable from your other symbols, so the rule is completely redundant. I suggest you review the definition of a CFG and how productions work.

Comment: @dkaeae So then the first rule should be aSbTc | a then and then second rule should be T -> bTcD | b and with D's rule changed to D --> Dc | c , that works, right?

Comment: Additionally, it's unclear from the question whether $i$, $j$, and $k$ are allowed to be 0. For example, should you be able to produce the string "$b$"?

Comment: @roctothorpe Yeah it's allowed to be 0 for any of them.

Answer (score 1):

The rules like "onions" with various layers that you describe in your question can be thought of as a *build order* for how you will construct a string -- eg. "first I will build this part of the string, and then I will build this other part" or "I need to build these two parts at the same time in order to ensure that they are synchronized".

> A good general strategy for constructing a context free grammar is to
> determine this build order and then have a production rule that
> represents each stage and/or each possibility of your build order.
>
> You should be able to point to each nonterminal and explain the "meaning"
> or type of string that nonterminal is trying to construct.

For the example of $a^ib^jc^k$ with $i \ne j$, one possible build order could be:

1. Produce $a$'s and $b$'s in equal number (this is like $a^ib^j$ where
   $i = j$. Try writing a grammar for this first.)
2. At some point, the number of $a$'s and $b$'s have to diverge, so pick either $a$ or $b$ and produce an unbounded number of that character (this is like $a^ib^j$ where $i \ne j$. Try taking the grammar you have from 1) and adding production rules to be able to do this.)
3. Now just produce an unbounded number of $c$'s at the end. (this is the desired $a^ib^jc^k$ with $i \ne j$.)

---

A good question to ask yourself:

Why do we have to have more than one production rule to construct $a^ib^j$ where $i \ne j$? If I want the number of $a$'s and $b$'s to be equal, it makes sense that I'd have to build them at the same time, but if I want $i \ne j$, why ***can't*** I just do something like:

$S \rightarrow aS\ |\ Sb\ |\ \varepsilon$

which says "produce some number of $a$'s and then produce some number of $b$'s"?